# UIActionSheet code crashes when moved from UIViewController file to separate class file

Tags: iphone, ios

I have searched and searched the board(s) and am not able to figure this out.  It has got to be something simple and right in front of me.

I am trying clean up my code and make it more reusable.  I was taking some UIActionSheet code that works from a UIViewController and making its own object file.  Works fine, until I add UIActionSheetDelegate methods.

When a button is pressed, instead of firing the actionSheetCancel method, it crashes with no stack trace.  Every time.

My code is below.  Any help would be appreciated. My guess has been it is because I am not using the xcode storyboard tool to connect things together, but I would think this is legal.

egcTestSheet.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface egcTestSheet : NSObject <UIActionSheetDelegate> {

}

- (void) showSheet:(UITabBar *) tabBar
    displayTitle:(NSString *) name;

@end
```

egcTestSheet.m

```
#import "egcTestSheet.h"

@implementation egcTestSheet

-(void) showSheet:(UITabBar *)tabBar displayTitle:(NSString *)name{

    UIActionSheet *menu = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:name
                                                      delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Done"
                 destructiveButtonTitle:@"Cancel"otherButtonTitles:nil];

   [menu showFromTabBar:tabBar];
   [menu setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 700)];

}

// actionsheet delegate protocol item
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex: (NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    NSLog(@"button index = %d", buttonIndex);
}


- (void)actionSheetCancel:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet{

    NSLog(@"in action canceled method");
}

@end
```

call code from a UIViewController object:

```
egcTestSheet *sheet = [[egcTestSheet alloc] init];

[sheet showSheet:self.tabBarController.tabBar displayTitle:@"new test"];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your action sheet is probably being released as it is dismissed (are you using ARC?). This means when it tries to call it's delegate to inform said delegate of its dismissal/selection, it is trying to call self. Self is a dangling pointer by this time, because it has been released.

In the view controller that is presenting/calling this action sheet, set a property to keep a reference to the action sheet. Set the property to nil on dismissal of the action sheet.

Comment: You hit it on the head.  Moved the creation to a @property (strong, nonatomic) and the issue went away.  It clearly was falling out of scope.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for an excellent answer. While it's fairly clear from the answer and the comment above, in case someone else encounters this, I thought I'd clarify that the @property (strong, nonatomic) you need to create is for the custom class object you're creating, not for the UIActionSheet object you use internally in your class.